# Install OpenCV 3.0.0 on eclipse - Ubuntu 14.04 32bit

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV 3.0.0 on eclipse. I followed [this](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/) guide to build OpenCV and now I am trying to install it on eclipse using [this guide](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html).

The problem is, there is no Java folder inside the build folder. What am I doing wrong?

**Output of cmake:**

```
 cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MARCH_I686
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MARCH_I686 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MARCH_I686
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MARCH_I686 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_AVX
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_AVX - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSSE3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_1
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_1 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MNO_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_2
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MNO_SSE4_2 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MFPMATH_SSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_MFPMATH_SSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MFPMATH_SSE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_MFPMATH_SSE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found TIFF: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (found version "4.0.3") 
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so  
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Found Jasper: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (found version "1.900.1") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so (found version "1.2.50") 
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h - found
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
-- checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   package 'gtk+-3.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
--   found gtk+-2.0, version 2.24.23
-- checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
--   found gthread-2.0, version 2.40.2
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   found gstreamer-base-0.10, version 0.10.36
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   found gstreamer-video-0.10, version 0.10.36
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   found gstreamer-app-0.10, version 0.10.36
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   found gstreamer-riff-0.10, version 0.10.36
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   found gstreamer-pbutils-0.10, version 0.10.36
-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   found libdc1394-2, version 2.2.1
-- checking for module 'libv4l1'
--   found libv4l1, version 1.0.1
-- checking for module 'libv4l2'
--   found libv4l2, version 1.0.1
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   found libavcodec, version 54.35.0
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   found libavformat, version 54.20.4
-- checking for module 'libavutil'
--   found libavutil, version 52.3.0
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   found libswscale, version 2.1.1
-- checking for module 'libavresample'
--   package 'libavresample' not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   package 'libgphoto2' not found
-- ICV: Removing previous unpacked package: /home/newton/Desktop/Java/Projects/Video/Jars/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack
-- ICV: Unpacking ippicv_linux_20141027.tgz to /home/newton/Desktop/Java/Projects/Video/Jars/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack...
-- ICV: Package successfully downloaded
-- found IPP (ICV version): 8.2.1 [8.2.1]
-- at: /home/newton/Desktop/Java/Projects/Video/Jars/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable exact version "2.7.6") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.4 (found suitable version "3.4.3", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is exact version "3.4.3")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
-- Found JNI: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/i386/libjawt.so  
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
--   videoio: Removing WinRT API headers by default
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.14.2-031402-generic i686
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.8.4)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fPIC   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fPIC   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fPIC   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fPIC   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so gtk-x11-2.0 gdk-x11-2.0 atk-1.0 gio-2.0 pangoft2-1.0 pangocairo-1.0 gdk_pixbuf-2.0 cairo pango-1.0 fontconfig freetype gstvideo-0.10 gstapp-0.10 gstbase-0.10 gstriff-0.10 gstpbutils-0.10 gstreamer-0.10 gobject-2.0 gmodule-2.0 gthread-2.0 xml2 glib-2.0 dc1394 v4l1 v4l2 avcodec avformat avutil swscale stdc++ dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libwebp ippicv
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 hal core flann imgproc ml photo video imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect superres ts features2d calib3d stitching videostab python2
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python3 viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.23)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.40.2)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.50)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.3)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 1.6.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.1)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 54.35.0)
--       format:                    YES (ver 54.20.4)
--       util:                      YES (ver 52.3.0)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 2.1.1)
--       resample:                  NO
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       video:                     YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       app:                       YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 0.10.36)
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.0.1) / libv4l2 (ver 1.0.1)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     8.2.1 [8.2.1]
--          at:                     /home/newton/Desktop/Java/Projects/Video/Jars/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use pthreads for parallel for:
--                                  YES
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/newton/Desktop/Java/Projects/Video/Jars/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.6)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.2)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.3)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:
--     mex:                         NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
--     PlantUML:                    NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/newton/Desktop/Java/Projects/Video/Jars/opencv-3.0.0/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/newton/Desktop/Java/Projects/Video/Jars/opencv-3.0.0/build
```

** **Update** **

It seems that I was missing the ant in the Java section:

```
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
```

After running:

```
sudo apt-get install ant
```

I got the output:

```
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.3)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               YES
--     Java tests:                  YES
```

but still, there is no Java folder in build folder.

Comment: can you add the cmake output with the question?

Answer (score 1):

## First

After you install ant then check the cmake

[image]

weather it shows java under to be built

currently it shows:

```
 Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python3 viz
```

## After that

build and make then check if there is src/org/opencv in the build folder.

If its there . find out if there is opencv-300.jar in build/bin

Then Follow this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html) for Eclipse then instead finding the jar in build/java add the .jar from build/bin

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you said, in the Uavailable line it says what it said before I installed ant, but the java is now missing from this line. But, in the "To be built:" line there is no java either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you deleted all the previous build configurations and file? I mean everything on the build folder?

Comment: Yes, I deleted everything and extracted the zip file I downloaded

Comment: Build it once and check if the build/bin contains the opencv-300.jar or not

Comment: it wont create a build/java in opencv 3.0.0 the jar will be located on build/bin intead of build/java

Comment: bin folder inside build folder is empty